# mognodb aggregation group by actor

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following **film** collection structure:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId,
   "title" : "movie-1",
   "actors" : [
      "actor-1",
      "actor-2",
      "actor-3",
   ],
   "categories" : [
     "category-1",
     "category-2"
   ]
 }
```

I want to display result of all actors with associate movies and categories as like as given below:

```
{
    "actor": "actor-1",
    "result": {
        "category-1": [ "movie-1", "movie-2" ],
        "category-2": [ "movie-1", "movie-4" ]
    }
}
```

I have tried aggregation as like as given below:

```
db.film.aggregate([
   {  $unwind: "$actors"  },
   {  $group: { 
        _id: "$actors", 
        data: {  $push: {  movie: "$title",   categories: "$categories"  } }
      }
   }, 
   {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        actor: "$_id",
        result: {
          $reduce: {
             input: "$data",
             initialValue: {},
             in: {
               $let: {
                  vars: { movie: "$$this.movie", categories: "$$this.categories" },
                  in: {
                     $arrayToObject: {
                         $map: {
                           input: "$$categories",
                           in: { k: "$$this",  v: "$$movie" }
                         }
                      }
                  }
               }
             }
           }
        }
      }
    }
 ])
```

But I get all actors list with only one movie with category as like as given below:

```
{
   "actor" : "actor-1",
   "result" : {
     "category-1" : "movie-1",
     "category-2" : "movie-2",
     "category-3" : "movie-3"
   }
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've **used a sledgehammer to crack a nut** (c)

Some stages could be replaced by `$reduce`, done inside `$project` stage (criticism and suggestions will be welcome)

```
db.film.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$actors"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$actors",
      data: {
        $push: {
          movie: "$title",
          categories: "$categories"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data.categories"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        actors: "$_id",
        categories: "$data.categories"
      },
      movies: {
        $push: "$data.movie"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      actor: "$_id.actors",
      result: {
        k: "$_id.categories",
        v: "$movies"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$actor",
      result: {
        $push: "$result"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      actor: "$_id",
      result: {
        $arrayToObject: "$result"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      actor: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3IsPT-Zeghp)

Answer (score 2):

You may need to do another `$unwind` on the `categories` array after flattening the `actors` array then group all the flattened docs by the two fields i.e. actor and category fields to create the movie titles list.

Another group to shape the result field is required.

The following pipeline should give you the desired result:

```
db.film.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$actors" },
    { "$unwind": "$categories" },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": { "actor": "$actors", "category": "$categories" },
        "movies": { "$push": "$title" }
    } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id.actor",
        "result": { 
            "$push": {
                "k": "$_id.category",
                "v": "$movies"
            }   
        }
    } },
    { "$addFields": {
       "result": { "$arrayToObject": "$result" }  
    } }
])
```